# htaccess RewriteRule automatically removes queue slashes

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have this in `.htaccess` file,

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Then if write in browser addres this url `site.com/asd////bla` and then in `index.php` if print `$_GET['url']`,  result is: `asd/bla`.

question: where is other slashes? why they are not printed ?

Comment: Extra slashes really shouldn't be there. It looks to me like a mistake in the URL. If you are using those slashes for anything else perhaps you should consider using a different character that doesn't affect the URL's structure.

Comment: i think the browser remove the slashes before he send the request... do you try a `wget site.com/asd////bla`?

Comment: @sil -the browser does not remove the slashes. They are still in the address bar... It's the server that is ignoring them...

Comment: @ota - You are welcome! You'll want to thank pekka too by upvoting his answer :)